# What is a good alternative of LTRIM and RTRIM in Java?

Tags: java, string, trim

What is a good alternative of JavaScript `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` functions in Java?

Comment: I was going to point you at Commons Lang StringUtils, but they don't have ltrim/rtrim (or lstrip/rstrip). +1 then...

Comment: @Thilo, yes they do. See my last edit to my answer.

Comment: @Max: Thanks, faith in my favourite library restored.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

With a regex you could write:

```
String s = ...
String ltrim = s.replaceAll("^\\s+","");
String rtrim = s.replaceAll("\\s+$","");
```

If you have to do it often, you can create and compile a pattern for better performance:

```
private final static Pattern LTRIM = Pattern.compile("^\\s+");

public static String ltrim(String s) {
    return LTRIM.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
}
```

---

From a performance perspective, a quick micro benchmark shows (post JIT compilation) that the regex approach is about 5 times slower than the loop (0.49s vs. 0.11s for 1 million ltrim).

I personally find the regex approach more readable and less error prone but if performance is an issue you should use the loop solution.

Comment: `replaceFirst` is better

Answer (score 34):

Using regex may be nice, but it's quite a lot slower than a simple trimming functions:

```
public static String ltrim(String s) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        i++;
    }
    return s.substring(i);
}

public static String rtrim(String s) {
    int i = s.length()-1;
    while (i >= 0 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
        i--;
    }
    return s.substring(0,i+1);
}
```

Source: http://www.fromdev.com/2009/07/playing-with-java-string-trim-basics.html

Also, there are some libraries providing such functions. For example, [Spring StringUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#trimLeadingWhitespace(java.lang.String)). 
Apache Commons StringUtils provides similar functions too: [strip, stripStart, stripEnd](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#strip%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
StringUtils.stripEnd("abc  ", null)    = "abc"
```

Comment: +1. I would not call this "trim" though, because String#trim does not trim whitespace, it trims control characters and some ASCII-only whitespace. Commons Lang calls their version (which does what you do and what everyone probably wants) "strip".

Comment: Another +1 if I could for the link to StringUtils in Spring, which has "trimLeadingWhitespace".

Comment: Yes, @Thilo is right. To make it work like original java trim function, just change the conditional to `s.charAt(i) <= ' '`.

Comment: But don't do that. That original trim spec seems just weird.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while(i >= 0 ...`? Otherwise, `rtrim( "  ")` returns a single space character.

Answer (score 11):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

private String rTrim(String str) {
    return StringUtils.stripEnd(str, /*stripChars*/" ");
}

private String lTrim(String str) {
    return StringUtils.stripStart(str, /*stripChars*/" ");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply try the following

```
String s = "  Hello world  "

String ltrim = s.stripLeading();

String rtrim = s.stripTrailing();
```

Comment: Good answer. This has been available since Java 11. No need anymore for custom code, or external libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Guava has [CharMatcher](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) trimLeadingFrom and trimTrailingFrom

e.g. `CharMatcher.whitespace.trimTrailingFrom(s)`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer of @bezmax I had a look at the Spring [`StringUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html), but it couldn't justify the overload for me of switching to the Spring framework. Therfore I decided to create a `Characters` class to easily left / right trim strings for any given character(-class). The class is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/kristian/characters).

```
Characters.valueOf('x').trim( ... )
Characters.valueOf('x').leftTrim( ... )
Characters.valueOf('x').rightTrim( ... )
```

If you would like to trim for whitespaces, there is a predefined character-class available:

```
Characters.WHITESPACE.trim( ... )
Characters.WHITESPACE.leftTrim( ... )
Characters.WHITESPACE.rightTrim( ... )
```

The class does feature also other kinds of character operations, such `condense`, `replace` or `split`.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit cheap, but you might also use these without any other library:

```java
final var string = "   Hello World   ";

final var rtrimmed = ("." + string).trim().substring(1);
// => "   Hello World"

var ltrimmed = (string + ".").trim();
ltrimmed = ltrimmed.substring(0, ltrimmed.length - 1);
// => "Hello World   "
```

I admit, that the `ltrimmed` is not that pretty, but it will do the trick.

Comment: Nice idea! Looks odd, but might well be the shortest way, syntactically. I use it in Elasticsearch Painless (Java-based) scripting where regexp is disabled by default.