# How to remove punctuations that possibly mark the end of a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string of the following form :

```
String s = "......????!!!!! I am doing!!!???good , you say!!! ...how are...??!! you doing!?????.....";
```

and I want the output of this string as follows :

```
"I am doing!!!???good you say how are you doing"
```

and I am not able to come up with a regular expression that can do this for me, what I am trying is a brute force way of scanning the string and appending to the text, but there are many cases to test this out, if someone can help me figure out a regex or a more efficient way to do this it would be great.

More specifically I want to be doing this : remove all the leading and trailing terminators but retain those that occur within a string as in "say????what"

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15567045/1558430). You will need to modify it to fit your needs, however.

Comment: I think it might be better to *ban* any user who use more than one punctuation mark at the end of a sentence :-)

Comment: I actually require this for a parsing routine, where I am just parsing some random text, but just can't seem to get the regex :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for your example:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=^| )[.?!]+|[.?!]+(?= |$)", "");
```

Tested this line and it produces your requested output.

It deletes all punctuation sequences next to a space or at either end.

Comment: No problem :) (You should probably accept this answer if it answers your question best)