# Remove whitespaces only from the right side of a String

Tags: java, string, replace, trim

I have a `String printerName;` which is 256 characters long. I need to remove whitespaces from right side of the String so that I get only a valid printer name.

This solution:

```
st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

doesn't work, because a valid printerName can have a whitespaces. And I don't know how many characters I have to delete, becouse there can be many printers. What's the best solution for this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567010/what-is-a-good-alternative-of-ltrim-and-rtrim-in-java/15567045#15567045

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to remove the spaces on the right (but not on the left) you can use:

```
st.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

The `$` anchor meaning the end of the string.

If you don't mind removing spaces at the beginning of the string as well, then:

```
st.trim()
```

will do the trick.