# JAVA 8 : Equivalent for LTRIM AND TO_CHAR of Oracle in Java

Tags: java, string-formatting

all, what is equivalent for TO_CHAR and LTRIM of Oracle in H2 or Java?

I have select statements like this :

`select LTRIM(TO_CHAR(colone,'009')) from Table;`

I want equivalent to make the treatment in java side.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Db2 has both TO_CHAR and LTRIM (on all platforms, synonym of VARCHAR_FORMAT).

Comment: Here is a possible answer you want in Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567010/what-is-a-good-alternative-of-ltrim-and-rtrim-in-java

Comment: @mao Thank you for ur reply, I wanted to write H2 but I would like to do java-side processing to be dependent on the database

Comment: `String.trim()` and `SimpleNumberFormat()`

Comment: I'd expect something like `String.format("%03d", colone)`. I don't see any reason to strip of the leftmost whitespace if no whitespace is produced by the format string. To the DB aficionados: is there any difference between specifying `000` and `009` as format string for `TO_CHAR`, because I don't see it.

Comment: H2 has both functions. See http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html